# Multithreading in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I am trying to create AMI of EC2 instances using python. I need to implement multi threading so that AMI creation can run in parallel. But below code is not working. It is creating single AMI at a time.

module1

```
from Libpy import Libpy
import boto.ec2
import sys
if __name__=='__main__':

  a = B()
  Libpy().multithreading(ec2list1,a.create_amibkp(ec2listname,ec2list1))
```

module2

```
import threading
import time

class Libpy:

    def multithreading(l, function):
        threads = []
        for z,v in enumerate(l):
            dummy = z
            t = threading.Thread(target=function, args=(v,))
            threads.append(t)
            t.start()
```

1. ec2listname  - contains the list of instance names for whom AMI
   creation should be done
2. ec2list1 - contains the list of instance ids for whom AMI creation should be done
3. create_amibkp - customized function which takes AMI for the filtered instances From module1, I am calling module2 to multithread the function but it is not working. It is creating AMI one at time. 
   4.B() - class will return ec2listname and ec2list1

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your example but I've created a dummy version:

```
import sys
import threading
import time
import random

random.seed(1)


class Libpy:

    def multithreading(self, lst, function):
        threads = []
        for v in lst:
            t = threading.Thread(target=function, args=(v,))
            t.start()
            threads.append(t)

        for t in threads:
            t.join()


def ami_creation(v):
    t = random.random() * 4
    print("creating ami {0}, sleeping {1}".format(v, t))
    time.sleep(t)
    print("ami {0} created ok".format(v))

ec2list1 = ["ec2-small", "ec2-medium", "ec2-large"]
Libpy().multithreading(ec2list1, ami_creation)

print("All boxes have been created...")
```

In the above example the main thread would wait till all boxes are created

Comment: In my answer I've showed you how to spawn multiple threads in parallel (no delay of triggering) and only when all threads have finished their business the main thread will continue executing, that's because of the line `for t in threads: t.join()`. I'd recommend reading about [thread-objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects), that will clarify much better than any short comment here

Comment: Hi, I am getting below error when trying to execute the AMI backups

BotoServerError: BotoServerError: 503 Service Unavailable
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>RequestLimitExceeded</Code><Message>Request limit exceeded.</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>30694d63-d23e-4f28-a892-ab9d958ca0fa</RequestID></Response>

Please help